# CPA Download offer leads (php, javascript, html, sql)

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

I got a download offer that I pay for every finished install,
so the affiliate network gives you a to fire a pixel you can choose postback url (No Cookies) or iframe/img (With Cookies).

so after the download and install i need to http request webpage (postback url or page with iframe/img)

but there is major issue with this, if someone has the pixel or postback url they can charge me for double leads or change ips and charge me once more. So anyone here have a solution for this kind of problem? Any solution will work :)

I just can't think of any, I only have basic programming understanding so anyone who can help me please really need this one.

Thanks!

P.S if you have a bullet proof solution just give me your moneybookers email too and I will donate you some cash for beer ^^ or if you think this something very hard just give me your price.

if you need more information how this tracking works
http://www.hasoffers.com/wiki/Application_Support:Offer_Tracking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ban ips after specific time frame lets say "7 days" OR include email verification, or credit card verifiction.